# ascii output of string compression in C

Tags: c, encryption, compression

I need to use both compression and encryption in a project. There are two programs in the project.

In the first program, an ascii text file is first compressed and then encrypted. Further operations follow on this encrypted version of the file. However, a second program in the project follows the reverse process i.e. first decrypts and then decompresses to get the original ascii text file.

I've implemented the encryption module (aes via openssl) and it works fine. But when i looked for compression options in linux, i found that gzip, zlib etc throw their own versions of the file i.e. filename.gz or some other extension, the contents of which are not purely ascii. (For instance, i see diamond shaped symbols when i view the output in the terminal) Beause of this, i'm unable to read the compressed file completely in my C program.

So in short, i require a compressed file which contains only ascii characters. Is this possible by any means?

Comment: Your encryption algorithm doesn't emit asci-only chars (thank god). Why such a limitation on your compressor? and since when can you not read a *binary* file in a C program?

Comment: You could postprocess the compressed output with [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) or comparable encoding but that costs you 25% efficiency (it's an 6 bits in 8 encoding).  It might be better to solve the problem that makes that your program cannot read binary encoded files.

Comment: By using an 'ASCII-only' representation of a compressed file, you'd undo most of the benefits of the compression.  The ASCII-only representation would occupy more space than the binary representation.  To read the file, use 'binary mode' (a no-op on Unix-like platforms, crucial on Windows).  And don't use string manipulation functions on the binary data; there _will_ be null bytes in the data (compressed or encrypted or both).

Comment: @fvu: 33%?  Base-64 grows by a third (requires 4 bytes out for each 3 in).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Same thing, different perspective 4/3 = 133% for 33% overhead, but 3/4 = 75% and 1 - 75% = 25% expansion...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler must be that despite a long career in IT I'm still an optimist :-)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - just wanted to note that there is one benefit of this approach: it helped me to "attach" a 460kB `.wrl` file to StackExchange (see [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14256/remove-empty-vertex-groups)); I used `XZ_OPT=-9 tar -cJO _2r_bga_export.wrl | base64 > out.xz.b64` and got 12.7kB `out.xz.b64` -- just about enough to paste it in a post.

Answer (score 2):

Finally resolved the issue. The program is handling everything correctly.

On the sending side:

```
compression: gzip -c secret.txt -9 > compressed.txt.gz
encryption: openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in compressed.txt.gz -out encrypted.txt
```

The compression output (gz) is given as an input for encryption which outputs a text file. The resulting output is purely ascii.

On the receiving side:

```
decryption: openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in decryptme.txt -out decrypted.txt.gz
decompression: gunzip -c decrypted.txt.gz > message.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add uuencode / uudecode filter in between compression and encryption -- or you might want to loosen the restriction of the compressed data to be in ascii form: options:

- read binary data from you c-program.
  (e.g.  `char buffer[256]; c=fread(buffer,1,256,stdin);` )
- convert the data to hexadecimal format
  `static char encrypted_file[]={ 0x01,0x6e, ... };`

Comment: Reading binary data even from stdin is an option

Comment: uuencode is a ghastly format because it can include spaces.  Use Base-64 encoding instead; it learns from uuencode and avoids the mistakes that uuencode made.

Comment: You are right. Just used it as an example of a reversible process stripping the MSB. Also for security purposes it's a bad candidate for having lot's of known plain-text.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Neither `uuencode` nor base64 encoding are intended to have any security implication whatsoever. They're both just simple encodings to use a reduced code set for transmission purposes (e.g. 8-bit unclean channels). base64 has as much "known plain-text" as `uuencode`, as does Huffman coding, arithmetic coding or any other algorithm whose sole purpose is to re-encode one set of code words into a different alphabet or structure (with apologies to the definitions that I just stretched way out of shape there).

Comment: uuencode has a structure: it begins typically with 'begin 644' and ends with backquote; also it contains periodical sequences CR+ascii M.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen if your protocol or algorithm cannot handle known plain text then you've got a lot to worry about anyway